# Are there a list of locations or features with known dimensions?

Tags: features, scale, mapping

I'm plotting lines and objects on a map and want to verify scales with real, physical objects on the map. Is there a list of physical features that are known distances?

Perhaps like the runway at Laguardia is 7000 feet long, exactly from this point to this point.

Or, this particular road is exactly due North, and this other is East-West.

Where is the calibrated list of map features bridges, roads, runways or road intersections that have known dimensions?

Comment: Maybe add which software you're working with? Because normally all data is aligned north, and you can easily measure distances in a GIS.

Comment: I'm working with open source ESRI imagery and also Google Earth. Both have different answers with their measured distances. Both are, in fact wrong to a certain extent, but it's unclear which is less wrong and by how much. I need surveyed landmarks to calibrate

Comment: No, you **think** you need landmarks for calibration. But probably it'd be way easier to do the measuring in QGIS, after choosing a fitting CRS.

Comment: Runway lengths are published by the FAA, also reproduced in many pilot-oriented websites.

Comment: runways would be quite useful but where are the starting and stopping locations? I guess it's an accuracy issue. It could work but I think there is better available

Comment: The US National Geodetic Survey sure has a lot of actively maintained locations collecting GPS locations all day and night at intervals of 1, 5, 15, and 30 seconds. The CORS stations have surveyed locations with very high accuracy. Centimeter level accuracy. https://geodesy.noaa.gov/

Comment: @Marc if you're interested in distances (*dimensioning*) then the runway lengths are a very reliable resource worldwide - however your comment above (start/stop locations) indicates you want georeferencing data as well. Could you click 'edit' and update your question with more information on exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Simbamangu, the question is clearly written. I'm looking for known distances to check maps for correlation to real life. the starting and stopping locations are not clear. Does the North-South runway at Washington Reagan start at the white stripes or the end of the pavement? How long is that runway anyway? Distance is from where to where?

Comment: Since posting the original question I located this impressive database with numerous georeferenced locations: https://geodesy.noaa.gov/NGSDataExplorer/ This is helpful somewhat but it's still not super easy to measure distances. It's a huge database of CORS locations. I sure could be missing something though

Comment: In your comment you mention "runways would be quite useful but where are the starting and stopping locations" which implies you need more than distances. We use runway markers to do this - there are usually 50m or 60m markers along the runway/airfield (at least in Africa - in USA they use different centreline distances I think).

Comment: runway length and visual measurement location is the unknown. exact geolocation on the planet is not super important. runway length and marker location (in the image) to know where to begin and end the measurement (on the image).

Comment: @Simbamangu, can you provide perspective on the various terminologies listed here? Runway markings, chevrons, shoulders, threshold, midpoint are all designated in this link. but what are the most obvious to see on an image that could be used in Google Earth Desktop for clear, easy, obvious point-to-point measurements? https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html

Comment: runway width with 16 stripes is 200ft , or 60m. that's a pretty good measurement that could be verified pretty well along the entire length. that seems it would work well (if I knew where a 16-stripe runway was located): Table 2-3-2, https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html#FIG_2_3_4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure known distances in Google Earth using runway centrelines, touchdown markers or side markings on airfields - these are usually exactly marked based on standards from the local aviation authority.

You want something which is clearly marked, large, and with a long enough distance  between or along markers to reduce measurement errors. From the [FAA](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap2_section_3.html) page on "Airport Marking Aids and Signs", you'll see mention of 'precision instrument runway' markers that include *touchdown zone* and *side markings*. Pilots and aviation authorities are rather concerned with precise measurements and I have measured side markings in a few countries and found them to be normally obsessively exact, except in some remote dirt airstrips.

Using the QuickMapServices plugin in QGIS, I add the Google Satellite and Bing map layers, confirm that it's using the 'ellipsoidal' option (which uses the default WGS84 ellipsoid EPSG:7030 (visible in Project Properties | General | Ellipsoid)), and check the distances between touchdown zone markings.

For example, [Daytona Beach International Airport runway 25R](https://www.google.com/maps/@29.1841094,-81.049517,698m/data=!3m1!1e3) has 4 touchdown markings - should be 1500 feet between them (FAA regulations):

[image]

#### Caveats

- This relies on a number of assumptions (and I'm fully expecting howls of outrage and hopefully some good advice from others after posting this):

  - The imagery is draped over a good DEM model (good assumption for international airports in USA / Europe). Check Kilimanjaro International Airport for example of some distortions - rw 27 side lines are straight on the ground, not from GE:
    [image]
  - Markings were measured accurately on the ground. I've only found significant variation in small airfields (and a minority of those), and never found more than a 0.1% variation on instrument/precision runways out of the 5 I've checked.

I'm not a member of an obsessive club of runway measurers ... during our aerial wildlife surveys ("Systematic Reconnaissance Flights" - SRF) we [measure or place ground markers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006320718318391) to calibrate visible "strip widths" as seen by human observers, and I've worked in 9 countries on airfields of various sizes. Actually I take it back, I guess SRF practitioners *are* obsessive runway measurers.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you would need to survey yourself on the ground or if there is national mapping organisation there use their data.

Comment: measuring myself is one possibility. it will be a good exercise, but I don't think I'm the first to need this. surveyed landmarks for calibrating maps is surely something publicly available. but where?

Comment: Marc, what you are wanting is something that has huge commercial value, you will have to pay for it to be accurate.

Comment: indeed, this is quite the valuable commodity. But have you seen the US National Geodetic Survey Data Explorer? Shazam. There is considerable investment in this network. It's all publicly available: https://geodesy.noaa.gov/

Comment: not the greatest data tbh.... not that impressive.